# ssh not recognised in Powershell 7

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell-7.3

`ssh` command can used in windows powershell which is system build-in,it like this:
[ssh in powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzxXl.png)

But when I use is in powershell7 which i download in github,`ssh` command do not work,it like this:
[ssh in powershell7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx0gW.png)

how I can solve it, I do not just want to change directory to `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` and use `.\ssh`

environment variables:

```
❯ $env:Path -split ';'

...
...
...

C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH

.
```

Comment: I have new discovery，when I change directory to `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` ，right click and `open in terminal`, the directory on powershell7 is not OpenSSH, it turn into `C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell\7`

Comment: Having the same issue.. it's really weird

Answer (score -1):

Run your PowerShell in admin mode.